# Is there a way to show Activity Indicator or Progress Bar during response wait from Alamofire api request? Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rest, api, alamofire

Right now I display progress bar that hardcoded to fill in 2 seconds (average response time). But I want it to be intelligent.

My request looks like this.

```
func makeRequest(to endPoint: String) {
    Alamofire.request(endPoint).responseJSON{ response in
        if let value = response.result.value {
            let responseInJSON = JSON(value)
            self._responseInJSON = responseInJSON
        }
    }
}
```

Looking forward for your help.
Thanks.

Comment: It would be impossible to time it perfectly to increase relative to your response time, since there is no way you could ever predict your response time.  It would be possible to have it hard coded to fill up to a certain point in 2 seconds, like close to the end, and then have it pause for a moment and wait until the response returns. You would then add something to animate it to quickly finish once the response comes completely in. You would call that final animation in the completion right after `self._responseInJSON = responseInJSON`. I know this isn't exactly what you want, just an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will help i have Indicate in Comment.

```
func makeRequest(to endPoint: String) {

    // here you can showActivetyIndicator start progressing here
    Alamofire.request(endPoint).responseJSON{ response in
        if let value = response.result.value {
            let responseInJSON = JSON(value)
            self._responseInJSON = responseInJSON
        }
       // here you can hide Your ActivetyIndicator here
    }
}
```

Simply you can start progress just before `Alamofire` request start and stop then after getting API response. no need for static time like 2 Sec.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple GET request this is unfortunately not possible due to restrictions with the HTTP protocol, not iOS. The only time this sort of thing is possible is when something like an video is downloaded through a bitstream, and then only if the server first tells the client the total file size.

Interestingly, the progress bar in Apple's own Messages and Safari apps are totally fake. If you observe them closely you'll see that the bar progresses at a solid rate to about 85%, where it will stop until the request has finished, at which point it will jump to the end. This is due to the aforementioned limitations to the HTTP protocol and it's not something Apple can do anything about.

You *can* however show a UIActivityIndicator to show the user that a network call is happening, you can create your own within your UI or just call `UIApplication.shared.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true` and subsequently false when your call finishes.

Not the answer you were hoping for but the truth unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

Here’s a way to do it in an extension that adds it to all of your UIViewControllers…

```
extension UIViewController {
    class func displaySpinner(onView : UIView) -> UIView {
        let spinnerView = UIView.init(frame: onView.bounds)
        spinnerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
        let ai = UIActivityIndicatorView.init(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)
        ai.startAnimating()
        ai.center = spinnerView.center

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            spinnerView.addSubview(ai)
            onView.addSubview(spinnerView)
        }

        return spinnerView
    }

    class func removeSpinner(spinner :UIView) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            spinner.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

To create and display the spinner, do this in your view controller:

```
let sv = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: self.view)
```

To remove

```
UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: sv)
```

Ref: http://brainwashinc.com/2017/07/21/loading-activity-indicator-ios-swift/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 spin.center = self.view.center
 spin.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .WhiteLarge
 self.view.addSubview(spin)
 spin.startAnimating()
 let url =  NSURL(string:StoreApi)

 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

 request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        Alamofire.request(request)
            .responseJSON { response in
                // do whatever you want here
                switch (response.result) {
                case .Success(let JSON):
                //do what you want after success
                case .Failure:

                }//switch close
                //Spin is my activity indicator
                 self.spin.stopAnimating()
                 self.spin.removeFromSuperview()
            }//responseJSON close
```